# if negative value less than zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to `addClass` to element if `value` less than zero, value is negative number `-0.3`, but what i tried so far not working.

```js
var rate = $('#view-ad-rating');
var text = parseInt($(rate).text());

if (text < 0) {
  $(rate).addClass('viewAdRateBad');
} else {
  //$(rate).addClass('viewAdRateGood');
}
```

```css
.viewAdRateBad {
  color: red;
}

.viewAdRateGood {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="view-ad-rating">-0.3</a>
```

I also tried this but no success:

```
if (text <= -1) {
```

How can solve this?

Comment: Try `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`. The "Int" means "integer".

Comment: @Pointy But the number can be positive, like `11` or `65` , no problem?

Comment: FYI an `int` is a whole number, so when you try to parse `-0.3` it is rounding to `0`.

Comment: Why would you name a number 'text'?

Comment: @JaredSmith Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the title of this thread... *negative numbers less than zero* ??? Sound really wrong to me :D. I mean, all numbers less then zero are negative

Comment: Also you can use `$(rate).toggleClass('viewAdRateBad', text < 0);` and  `$(rate).toggleClass('viewAdRateGood', text >= 0);`

Comment: @JaredSmith Now understand, because ** text of div** how can get the element value?? with `text()`

Comment: @tourtravel you're parsing the value from the DOM as a *number*, so it's a number, not text. Naming things is important: when I see a variable named 'text' I expect it to be a string, not a number.

Comment: @Dwza Are you ok? the title is `if negative value less than zero`

Comment: @tourtravel it's redundant, 'less than zero' is what 'negative' *means*... which is the source of the confusion.

Comment: @JaredSmith funny, now the problem is my naming? :)  i just create a sample for you, i named `text` because i get value by `text()` end of the story

Comment: @tourtravel what JaredSmith try to say to you, is that your variable name is not really the best one. You can use text() to retrieve it, but for exemple, it would be better if your variable "text" was named "adRatingValue" for example.

Comment: @tourtravel until you go to modify this code 6 months from now, and call a string method on the variable because text means string, and it throws an error and you waste 10 minutes or more figuring out why. Be kind to your future self.

Comment: @JaredSmith you right :) but i don't think I search this part of my code with this stupid variable name .. I always going to search by `ID` or `Class`. Anyway, Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @tourtravel yes... i guess it should be just called `if value less than zero` or `if value is negative`

Comment: Thanks for down vote ;)

Comment: @tourtravel i didnt give you any votes... i just commented your obviously sentence mistake :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` because `parseInt` just parses the first part as `0` and it is not negative. Working code:

```js
var rate = $('#view-ad-rating');
var text = parseFloat($(rate).text()); // <- HERE

if (text < 0) {
  $(rate).addClass('viewAdRateBad');
} else {
  //$(rate).addClass('viewAdRateGood');
}
```

```css
.viewAdRateBad {
  color: red;
}

.viewAdRateGood {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="view-ad-rating">-0.3</a>
```

```
parseInt("-0.3")
//returns -0

parseFloat("-0.3")
//returns -0.3

parseInt("-0.9") // note it doesn't round but just parses the first part
//returns -0
```